# Zipping all files in a dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using RubyZip in attempts to zip all the files in a directory. Here's my class:

```
require 'zip/zip'
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :attachment, :course_id, :goal, :title, :assets_attributes
    belongs_to :course
    has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:asset_file_name].blank? }

    def bundle
    bundle_filename = "public/attachments/#{self.id}/#{self.id}.zip"

    Zip::ZipFile.open(bundle_filename, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) {
    |zipfile|
        Dir.foreach("public/attachments/#{self.id}") do |item|
        zipfile.add( item, "public/attachments/")
      end
   }

    File.chmod(0644, bundle_filename)
    self.save
    end
end
```

Currently, this is creating a zipfile with the name that I want, but the files in the directory aren't being zipped correctly. They aren't being zipped as files but as directories.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail: what is your expected output and what are you actually getting? *"...being zipped as files but as dirs..."* can be interpreted a couple of ways, so please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on a Linux server, you could try [unix_utils](https://github.com/seamusabshere/unix_utils):

```
tmp_filename = UnixUtils.zip "public/attachments/#{self.id}"
bundle_filename = "public/attachments/#{self.id}/#{self.id}.zip"
FileUtils.mv tmp_filename, bundle_filename
File.chmod 0644, bundle_filename
```

The first line zips everything in `public/attachments/#{self.id}` to a file (`tmp_filename`) in the tmp directory. Then you move and rename this file to `bundle_filename`.

Comment: what I mean is that it creates dirs with the names of the files i want zipped from the attempted main directory. fo for example if a file called readme.txt existed in the dir then in the zipfile "readme.txt" would be added as a folder, not as the intended text file.