# Zipping files in a directory with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip

I'm trying to zip all the files contained in a directory using RubyZip. Here's what I have:

```
def bundle
      #create the ZIPfile with the title of (:id).zip
bundle_filename = "public/attachments/#{self.id}/#{self.id}.zip"

      #open the ZIPfile in order to add items in
Zip::ZipFile.open(bundle_filename, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) {
  |zipfile|
    Dir.foreach("public/attachments/#{self.id}") do |item|
    t = File.open(item)
    zipfile.add(t, "public/attachments/#{self.id}")
    end
  }

    #change permissions on ZIPfile
  File.chmod(0644, bundle_filename)
  self.save
  end
```

This succesfully executes the first line and creates the zip file with the correct name but it is not adding all the files contained in that directory. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the `Dir.foreach` call is adding items? You could use `Rails.logger` to debug this.

Comment: Check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525484/zipping-all-files-in-a-dir

Comment: Wohooo, is the same question from same user ;)

Answer (score 4):

Make your life easy and use command line functions in the ruby method:

In this implementation, I'm zipping a rails directory, so I access the full path to that directory with the help of Rails functions. You can specify the entire path yourself.

```
path = Rails.root.to_s + "/public/tmpFiles"
archive = path + "/tempFilesArchive.zip"
puts "Path: #{path}"
puts "Archive: #{archive}"
`rm "#{archive}"` # remove the archive file, if it exists.
`zip -rj "#{archive}" "#{path}"` # zip the contents of the directory
```

This should create a zipfile called "tempFilesArchive.zip" in the same directory that you zipped.

Answer (score 1):

I Don't know if this is the most correct way but this works for me.
This zips all the files and folders from dir in zip

```
  require 'zip/zip'

   def bundle
      bundle_filename = "abc.zip"
      FileUtils.rm "abc.zip",:force => true
      dir = "testruby"
      Zip::ZipFile.open(bundle_filename, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) { |zipfile|
        Dir.foreach(dir) do |item|
          item_path = "#{dir}/#{item}"
          zipfile.add( item,item_path) if File.file?item_path
        end
      }
     File.chmod(0644,bundle_filename)
   end
```